# Using FFMPEG: Is it possible to dynamically rotate a png using a file with timestamps and data (angles) as input?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to do something weird, hear me out.
I want to overlay a compass on a video, with motion captured rotation vectors in a log file, dynamically determining the orientation of the compass.

I know I should be using blender for this, but I can't. Also, I already have a glorious bash script where ffmpeg does all sorts of stuff. It would be fantastic if I could add this functionality to the script.

Alternatively, does anyone know how this could be done in a scriptable way?
Thanks for your help :)

Edit: Here is [one of my videos](https://youtu.be/KZ-C42EF4mY?t=1866), if you want to see the application. I am wearing a logging AHRS, and would like a compass in the lower left corner :)

Answer (score 0):

I've never solved this problem.

I would break it into components to solve.

From what I've read, I would start by taking the info about the video you are merging with so that you can generate an overlay video as close to those specs (frame rate, colorspace, that type of thing) as possible (to simplify the job ffmpeg has to do to merge them).  I'm not sure how important it is, but it seems like it should tend to help/improve quality.

I suggest using that info to create a much smaller video (e.g. a few (20-50?) pixels square, to put in the corner of the original), ideally with an alpha channel to make the overlay conserve as much original data as possible, that shows the direction of the compass that matches up with the times in the video.

Then use ffmpeg to overlay the smaller video with alpha channel on top of the original to create a new one that shows both.

The linked SE articles may be relevant:

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/add-an-image-overlay-in-front-of-video-using-ffmpeg

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467594/ffmpeg-add-alpha-channel-to-a-video-using-a-png-mask

https://kb.tecplot.com/2019/02/27/use-ffmpeg-to-create-videos-from-pngs/

My guess for how to start creating the images:

Take the existing frame rate for your current video, combine with duration to get total number of frames: f

Create f images such that image number n (such that n * seconds/frame = the timestamp of the direction measurement) is a small PNG (with alpha channel for the background so it doesn't obscure the background unnecessarily) of a compass rotated to that direction measurement.

E.g. if at time t=0s, frame rate 4frames/second (== 1second/4frames = 1/4 seconds/frame), the direction is 0 degrees, and at time t=1 seconds, the direction is 20 degrees, and time t=3 seconds, the direction is 35 degrees:

```
Frame, direction:
1, 0
2, 0
3, 0
4, 20
5, 20
6, 20
7, 20
8, 20
9, 20
10, 20
11, 20
12, 35
13, 35
...
etc.
```

You can probably get away with just 36 different PNGs, and round everything to the nearest 10 degrees (e.g. 33 degrees rounds to 30 degrees, 36 degrees rounds to 40, etc.) if you want to avoid having to create 360 different PNGs.